# Webpack duplicates packages in bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Here is the output from bundle-analyzer:

[image]

As you can see packages as react-dom, jquery and mobx are both in shell bundle and vendor bundle. Is it possible to put them only in vendor bundle?

**UPDATE**
Here is config file:

```
entry: {
    shell: './src/shell.ts',
    vendor: [
      'jquery',
      'react',
      'react-dom',
      'react-router',
      'mobx',
      'mobx-react',
      'toastr',
      'styled-components',
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: '[name]bundle.js?[hash:8]',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  devtool: PROD ? false : 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json'],
    modules: ['node_modules'],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: !!PROD,
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css?[hash:8]', {
      allChunks: true,
      disable: !PROD,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
      template: './src/index.tpl.html',
    }),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
  ],
```

Comment: Can you show your webpack config file.

Comment: Sure, I updated my question. (I didn't include "module" object)

Answer (score 7):

You can split all your vendor code comming from the `node_modules` folder into a single `vender` bundle file using `splitChunks` optimization webpack setting.

Firstly, remove `vendor` form your `entry`.

Then, add the below code to your `config` file:

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            vendors: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/ ,
                name: 'vendor' ,
                chunks: 'all' ,
                enforce: true ,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're manually splitting code using `entry` which has some pitfalls, [e.g.](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/):

> If there are any duplicated modules between entry chunks they will be included in both bundles.

You can prevent it either with `Entry dependencies` or `SplitChunksPlugin` .

Here's an example for `Entry dependencies`:

```
entry: {
    shell: {import: './src/shell.ts', dependOn: 'vendor'},
    vendor: [
      'jquery',
      'react',
      'react-dom',
      'react-router',
      'mobx',
      'mobx-react',
      'toastr',
      'styled-components',
    ],
  },
```

Since you're going to use both entrypoints in a same HTML page, remember to enable `optimization.runtimeChunk: 'single'`.

There're detail explanations on [code splitting guide for webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prevent-duplication), you can read over there too.